# How to pass arguments in Spyder using sys argv

Tags: python, spyder

I am struggling with passing 2 arguments in spyder using the command line. I have used the run-->configuration per file and in the command line options put `JPEGtoPNG.py/Poxedex/new/.` The JPEGtoPNG is the python file and the arguments to be passed are poxedex and new.

Dilemma:
When i run `print(sys.argv[0])` it prints:

```
runcell(0, '/Users/chideraokafor/JPEGtoPNG.py')
```

which i understand is the default.
However when i run `print(sys.argv[1])` it prints:

```
IndexError: list index out of range.
```

I have tried everything but still, it's not passing the two arguments, and I really don't want to use pycharm.

Comment: Please see my answer in the question I referenced above. Also, that doesn't work for cells, only when you run the entire file.

Answer (score 0):

If `Poxedex` and `new` are command line arguments for a script, *JPEGtoPNG.py*, execution should be:

```sh
python JPEGtoPNG.py Poxedex new
```

Not `/` separated.

Note that the error you get is because you are not passing command line arguments and as such [sys.argv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv) is a list of length one (that one being the script name) and indexing starts at `0` in Python so accessing the *second* element via `sys.argv[1]` is indeed out of range.

Since Spyder provides a Python console and the options you are passing via the menu are intended as that - *options* and not arguments - you might find it easier to run the script(s) from the command line, for example using VSCode.

Even if you don't want to use VSCode, you can just open a terminal window and invoke the script from there. Just check your environment variables to ensure Python is on your system (or user) path.